# To check what iOS version used by my app users

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app published on the AppStore. 
I plan to change the minimal requirement of my app to iOS 5.x because there's an issue that only exists in iOS4 and it has been fixed in iOS5.
Is there any easy way to check what iOS version used by my existed users?
I want to know the statistics so I can decide whether to change the min requirement is OK or not
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to check this would be if you had **already** written code to send usage statistics such as `[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion`, `[UIDevice currentDevice].localizedModel`, `[UIDevice currentDevice].systemName`, etc to yourself (a webserver/db you control) in your current App.

If it is not currently coded in your live App, then there is no way to determine this information.  It may be a good idea however to program this in to your next update for future situations such as this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add code for this, such as analytics or sending back, you also need to be careful with analytics as Apple discourages sending device information, but OS should be ok. The answer is no, not without recompiling, perhaps crash reports might give you an idea, but there's nothing else you can do.

Perhaps you would care to ask how to fix the issue instead?

Answer (score 0):

you might use some service like [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com) to track what version people are using.